# Variables in CSS / Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter

Hey, I'm trying to set variables in my CSS so that I can allow subscribers to customize the colors of their page. I'd rather have as many files on my static server as possibly.

Is there a good / easy way to do this?  Should I just have a CSS file containing all the editable parameters in a CSS file inside the application?

Walker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this:

1. Use PHP to output your CSS file that contains all the editable CSS values (make sure you remember to set the mime type of the file to text/css).
2. Alternatively, you could tell the web server to parse CSS files for PHP code (Apache in the example below).

This goes in your site's .htaccess file (tells the server to look for PHP in CSS files):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

This goes at the very top of your CSS file so browsers treat it as a CSS file:

```
<?php Header ("Content-type: text/css");?>
```